# How would I have a certain block of code ignored after a certain function fires with JS? For example

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have sort of a vague question that I hope somebody can help me with. Unfortunately, I don't have that much experience yet with JavaScript and am slowly learning it (painstakingly).

Anyways my issue is that I have a fixed menu bar that expands with a scroll toggle method. That same menu bar also has the feature that it hides when you scroll down and is visible again when you scroll back up (save screen space).

The issue here is that when the menu is expanded I don't want it to disappear anymore on scroll down.

Now I was thinking if there was someway to easily code something like [if you fire the function with the scroll toggle method > ignore the code that tells you to hide on scroll down.

I'm sure this is something really simple I just can't quite seem to figure it out.

Admittedly I did not write the code for the hide menu feature, but did make some slight changes to it based on the little things I'm learning with JS.

Thanks for any help!!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

 jQuery(".toc").click(function() {

  $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
  jQuery(".sidebar ul").slideToggle({
   progress: function() {

    $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
   }

  });
  
 });

});


//HIDE MENU .SIDEBAR WHEN SCROLLING A LITTLE DOWNWARDS (CAN WE IGNORE THIS WHEN ABOVE FIRES? IS THAT THE PRACTICAL METHOD)

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.sidebar').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.sidebar').hide();
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.sidebar').show();
        }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 1000px
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 1;
}
.sidebar ul {
  display: none;
}

.table-holder {
  height: 40px;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}

.content {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 75%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
      <!--Side Bar-->
     <div class="sidebar">

            <!--Table of Contents-->
            <div class="toc">
              <p>Table of Contents</p>
            </div>

              <ul>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
              </ul>

     </div><!--Side Bar Close-->
          
          <!--Table Holder Div to Push Content Down-->
          <div class="table-holder"></div>
          
          <!--Content Divs-->
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="content">
          </div>
          
          <div class="content">
          </div>
          
          <div class="content">
          </div>
          
          <div class="content">
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that stores the state of your menu and conditional statements to control what you want to do while its closed or open.

for example:

```
var menuState = "Hide";

if(menuState == "Hide") {
   function hide() { ... }
}
```

Here the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/73z9p9uk/1/

var open = false;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery(".toc").click(function() {
        !open ? open = true : open = false; 
        $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
        jQuery(".sidebar ul").slideToggle({
            progress: function() {

                $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
            }

        });

    });

});


//HIDE MENU .SIDEBAR WHEN SCROLLING A LITTLE DOWNWARDS (CAN WE IGNORE THIS WHEN ABOVE FIRES? IS THAT THE PRACTICAL METHOD)

var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.sidebar').outerHeight();


$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    if(!open) {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.sidebar').hide();
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.sidebar').show();
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Asperger! Thanks for the quick reply! It seems to work except that now the menu doesn't hide when you scroll down.

Comment: Please correct first block of code. You can not wrap a function by if statement. If statement should be inside of functions (as well as second block of code)

Comment: @AliSheikhpour did I wrap it?

Comment: @darthlaroque oh hey darth. Sure no problem. Give me a sec. Also ill clean up your code :D

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you so much Asperger I really appreciate all of the help! Honestly without you guys learning this would be 10 times harder. I hope one day to be a prolific JS coder and be able to help others myself.

Comment: @darthlaroque try your jsfiddle now

Comment: For your info. You can reduce more than half of the code if you dont use JQuery : )

Comment: WOW! That is working beautifully! Thank you so much for the help! It is truly appreciated. It's working so much better. I'd like to send the link to the website once I finally have it launched.

Comment: @darthlaroque ill make a room for you. Ill show you some cool tricks real fast

Comment: Now I will have the pleasure of poring over the code and learn how you did that. Fantastic! You are a life saver!

Comment: Damnit I don't have enough reputation to talk yet :(

Comment: @darthlaroque you can talk now. Try it

Comment: Hey just tried chatting again. Still can't chat. Says I need 20 reputation to talk.

Comment: @darthlaroque check your reputation. It says you have 20 :D

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

```
    jQuery(".toc").click(function() {
    if ( canHide === true) {
       canHide = false;
    }
    else {
      canHide = true;
    }

        $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
        jQuery(".sidebar ul").slideToggle({
            progress: function() {

                $(".table-holder").css("height", $(".sidebar ul").height());
            }

        });

    });

});


//HIDE MENU .SIDEBAR WHEN SCROLLING A LITTLE DOWNWARDS (CAN WE IGNORE THIS WHEN ABOVE FIRES? IS THAT THE PRACTICAL METHOD)
var canHide = true;
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('.sidebar').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll && canHide) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.sidebar').hide();
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.sidebar').show();
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the code you want to ignore in this:

```
if(dontIgnore){
    //code
}
```

and to start ignoring the code, just set dontIgnore to false:

```
dontIgnore=false;
```

To stop ignoring again, if you need to:

```
dontIgnore=true;
```

**Don't forget to define "don't-ignore" and set it to true at the beginning of your code!**

Good luck!

Note: Untested.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Feathercrown I'm going to read more about this feature!

Answer (score 0):

The most general answer to this question is to define a **global variable** **outside of all function** e.g. `var status='active';` and change it to `status='inactive'` when some conditions happen. Inside all other functions you have to check `if (status=='active')` to continue.

Please remind that you can not wrap the whole code or whole function by *if statement* because this would work just in first run. Instead you have to use *if statement* inside the functions.

Comment: Thanks Ali! Like I said I'm very new to JS so things like this give me real headaches!

Comment: Anyway -1 is for wrong answers not for like and dislike.

Comment: That wasn't me that pressed -1. I actually upvoted. Thanks Ali.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the onscroll function to remove the outer if else

```
if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('.sidebar').hide();
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('.sidebar').show();
        }
    }
```

To

```
 // Scroll Up
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
        $('.sidebar').show();
    }
```

Since it's documentation shows that's the part that runs on scroll down event